# How to highlight the lowest curve (envelope) among multiple curves in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, matplotlib, plot

Say I have multiple math functions `f1`, `f2`, `f3` represented by Python functions. I want to plot them together on the domain of [0, 1]. Here is what it looks like

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

def f1(x):
    return 4*x**3 + 9*x**2 + x + 4
def f2(x):
    return math.sqrt(x) / (1.01 - x)
def f3(x):
    return 30 * math.cos(6 * x)

x = np.arange(0.0, 1.01, 0.01)
for f in [f1, f2, f3]:
    vecf = np.vectorize(f)
    y = vecf(x)
    plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlim([0, 1])
plt.xlabel(r'$x$')
plt.ylabel(r'$f(x)$')
plt.show()
```

[image]

However, I want to highlight all lowest curve segments (i.e. the envelope) by using `alpha = 1`, while using `alpha = 0.5` for other parts of the curves. I want to keep the color of each curve. The expected plot looks something like this:
[image]

Can anyone suggest how to achieve this in matplotlib?

Comment: I don't know if there's an easy way to do this in matplotlib, but an approach that occurs to me is to just plot all curves, then compute a series that is effectively the minimum of the others combined and plot that as well, but with a 100% transparant line colour and shading the entire area above it in partially opaque white.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a shot at doing what I suggested in the comments ("to just plot all curves, then compute a series that is effectively the minimum of the others combined and plot that as well, but with a 100% transparant line colour and shading the entire area above it in partially opaque white.") and I think it's pretty close to what you need:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

def f1(x):
    return 4*x**3 + 9*x**2 + x + 4
def f2(x):
    return math.sqrt(x) / (1.01 - x)
def f3(x):
    return 30 * math.cos(6 * x)

x = np.arange(0.0, 1.01, 0.01)
# initialise min_y to all infinite, there is probably a more efficient way to do this
min_y = np.inf * np.ones(x.shape)
for f in [f1, f2, f3]:
    vecf = np.vectorize(f)
    y = vecf(x)
    # zorder=0 to push curves below plane 
    plt.plot(x, y, zorder=0)
    # compute min_y as we go
    min_y = np.minimum(y, min_y)

# what you need, although the +1 is a bit arbitrary
# you may want to add some amount relative to the plt.ylim()
plt.fill_between(x, min_y+1, plt.ylim()[1], color='white', alpha=.5)

plt.xlim([0, 1])
plt.xlabel(r'$x$')
plt.ylabel(r'$f(x)$')
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Maybe you want an alpha more like .7 or so, judging from your example.

Sneaky follow-up question, to also make the lines fat:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

def f1(x):
    return 4*x**3 + 9*x**2 + x + 4

def f2(x):
    return math.sqrt(x) / (1.01 - x)

def f3(x):
    return 30 * math.cos(6 * x)

x = np.arange(0.0, 1.01, 0.01)
# initialise min_y to all infinite, there is probably a more efficient way to do this
min_y = np.inf * np.ones(x.shape)
plotted = []
for f in [f1, f2, f3]:
    vecf = np.vectorize(f)
    y = vecf(x)
    # zorder=0 to push curves below plane
    p = plt.plot(x, y, zorder=0)
    # compute min_y as we go
    min_y = np.minimum(y, min_y)
    # keep the plotted data, to reuse when plotting fat lines
    plotted.append((y, p[0].get_color()))

for y, c in plotted:
    plt.plot(x, np.ma.masked_where(y > min_y, y), color=c, zorder=1, linewidth=3)

# what you need, although the +1 is a bit arbitrary - you may want to add some amount relative to the plt.ylim()
plt.fill_between(x, min_y+1, plt.ylim()[1], color='white', alpha=.7)

plt.xlim([0, 1])
plt.xlabel(r'$x$')
plt.ylabel(r'$f(x)$')
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: curves with shaded upper area and fat lines for relevant sections]

Comment: This is an interesting idea. May I ask, if I also want to increase the linewidth of the lowest curve (or decrease the linewidth of the other parts), what would you do?

Comment: I've added an extended solution that does that as well - for further tweaks, I suggest accepting the answer, working with it and if you have further questions, post a new question, since this already goes beyond you initial question (and will make the answer harder to find)